# ECSlidingViewController cause to mistake when dismiss UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller

When I use ECSlidingviewController  dismissing to last of controller return to top controller instead of parent;

My Controllers order like this in storyboard ;

> InitialViewController (UIViewController) --> HomeNavigationController (UINavigationController) --> HomeController  (UIViewController) --> MovieDetailController  (UIViewController)  --> CommentViewController  (UIViewController)

There is no problem until presenting CommentViewController after this it returns to InitialViewController

**LOGS: MovieDetailController --> CommentViewController:**

```
self = <MovieDetailViewController: 0xb3c15c0>
super = <HomeNavigationViewController: 0xa77c640>
nav_cont = (
"<HomeViewController: 0xa77c930>",
"<MovieDetailViewController: 0xb3c15c0>")
```

**CommentViewController viewDidLoad:**

```
self = <CommentViewController: 0x137154e0>
super = (null)
presenting = <InitialViewController: 0xb34ad70>
nav_cont = (null)
```

There is a problem in this line: 
**presenting = InitialViewController: 0xb34ad70** 
it should be 
    **MovieDetailViewController: 0xb3c15c0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out, if you give a UINavigationController after InitialViewController ECSliding does not work correctly. UINavigatonController must be root of all UIViewController.

**This is wrong:**

InitialViewController (UIViewController) --> HomeNavigationController (UINavigationController) --> HomeController (UIViewController) --> MovieDetailController (UIViewController) --> CommentViewController (UIViewController)

**This is right:**

HomeNavigationController (UINavigationController) --> InitialViewController (UIViewController) --> HomeController (UIViewController) --> MovieDetailController (UIViewController) --> CommentViewController (UIViewController)